# Load jQuery into <body>

Tags: php, jquery

My structure is the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include('form.php')?>
    <script src='jquery.js'>
  </body>
</html>
```

My php include do not executes my jQuery functions...

I put my jQuery functions in form.php with a:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.newBooking').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("data-date"));   
    });
});
```

But nothing...

Is it normal ?

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
<script src='jquery.js'>
<?php include('form.php')?>
```

Your code doesn't work because you try to use jQuery before it is loaded.
Even you use `$(document).ready` you call the jQuery function. So you use it...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use jQuery before it is defined. Put the jQuery file before the included file

Comment: But `$(document).ready(function() {` must wait all pages is load no ?

Comment: document.ready isn't defined until you load jQuery. Try moving it like steven suggested and see if you get a different result

Comment: To be a bit more specific, it's `$` that isn't defined until jQuery has been loaded.